# Read RSS feeds with atom support

Tags: android, rss, feed, atom-feed

Hello i am looking for a code snippet or even better for an android library for reading rss (atom) feeds. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROME](https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/) is a closed-source, feed reader for Android. If you need help, I've used the [J2SE version of it](http://rometools.jira.com) extensively, but not the Android version, so feel free to ask.

Comment: I know Rome and i cant get it to work in android. I think the j2se version is using beans internally, isnt?

Comment: I linked to the android version of it. If it doesn't work, you can try the J2SE version

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this open source library:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It's very lightweight and easy to use. It supports RSS2 and Atom by default but allows you to plug in your own custom parser as well.

For example, the following code loads a feed url in the background:

```
 PkRSS.with(this).load(url).async();
```

There are more details on the GitHub page.